# Terminate a running websocket connection

Tags: python, ssl, websocket

I've inherited a problem that I'm rather stuck on and wondered if anyone could give me some guidance. Apologies if the questions I ask are stupid ones...

A Python program makes a websocket connection to an AWS server to read a queue of messages and write them to a file. It would terminate the connection after some time, close the file, and proceed with whatever the rest of the program does:

```
    print("##############################################")
    print("Starting the retreiving process")
    ws = websocket.WebSocketApp(ws_url,
                                header={'authorization':'Basic ' + auth},
                                on_message=on_message,
                                on_error=on_error,
                                on_close=on_close)
                                #if error exit
    print("Connected to websocket")
    ws.on_open = on_open
    wst=threading.Thread(target=ws.run_forever)
    print("Starting the retreiving process")
    wst.start()
    time.sleep(float(active_time))
    ws.keep_running=False
    wst.join()
    print("############## DONE #######################")
```

This worked fine.  However, we have added the following sslopt to the ws.run_forever statement, to bypass SSL certificate checks:

```
wst=threading.Thread(target=ws.run_forever(sslopt={"cert_reqs": ssl.CERT_NONE}))
```

The websocket thread now stays connected (seven days and counting).

Two questions:

1. Is this expected behaviour?  Does the bypassing of SSL certificate checks affect the ws.keep_running=False?
2. How can I best terminate the running connection, without killing the job altogether?  I'd like it to go on to close its file and exit gracefully.

Comment: Why do you _need_ to keep the connection alive, rather than just having some sensible session management (remember, websockets are _web_ sockets, not bare TCP or UDP connections, they start life as a plain HTTP call with an `upgrade` request) that allows for disconnects and reconnects?

Comment: Do you mean the use of run_forever?  What would have been a more sensible way of starting the connection?

Comment: Mostly I'm wondering whether you _need_ a persistent connection. What is it actually doing that requires run_forever rather than just keeping it alive by actually _using_ it (i.e. having your own ping/pong so both your client and server know it's still active, or just closing it and reopening it when you actually need it)

Comment: To be honest, I don't know.  (I've been handed this program that was written by a team that has since left the organisation!)  From what you say, it could do with a major overhaul.  What it should do is: connect twice a day, gather whatever's in the queue and write it to a file at our end, disconnect.  What would you suggest?

Comment: Then Just use a simple wrbsocket Connection without this Webserver App etc..

Comment: Thanks, both of you, for your comments.  I'm completely new to this and I'm struggling to understand why it's been written as it has.  Do you have any thoughts on whether it might be possible to terminate the websocket thread (of the program that is currently running) and return control to the Python program, so that the file can be closed cleanly and the rest of the program complete?

Comment: It's a bidirectional data connection, so normally you just "send a message to let the other side know about what's going to happen". Say you want to close the connection and get the other side to do so cleanly with a file write, you just send a message with a name/payload that both parties understand to mean that thing, and then when the receiver gets that message, it can go "ok", close its side of the websocket, and then do what it needs to do based on the message it got.

Comment: Thank you so much.  That's really helpful.  I think that gives me a slightly better understanding of how these things work.  Thanks for your time.

Comment: But would I be able to do that from another session?